# "this" undefined inside promise react native

Tags: react-native, promise

I have below code

```
saveUsers(data){
// save
}
 _onPressButton() {
      Promise.then(() => {
            getInfo((err, contacts) => {
                if (err === 'denied') {
                    alert('denied')
                    // error
                } else {
                    this.saveUsers(info)
                }
            })
        }).catch(err => {
            alert(err);
        })
    }
```

**this.saveUsers(info)** Throws error

```
undefind is not a function(evaluating '_this2.saveUsers')
```

Please help me to understand this

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to make your functions arrow functions. Seems like for onPressButton 'this' is not available

Comment: Ooops, I had missed that.

Answer (score 0):

```
 saveUsers(data){//save
 } _onPressButton = () => {
  Promise.then(() => {
        getInfo((err, contacts) => {
            if (err === 'denied') {
                alert('denied')
                // error
            } else {
                this.saveUsers(info)
            }
        })
    }).catch(err => {
        alert(err);
})
}
```

try this. your onclick is not getting the context. use fat arrow or bind from the class.